# mutlithreading command line in python

Tags: python, multithreading, command-line

I'm looking for a way to run my python script on several files, and as it finishes each file, it runs a command line to xcopy the file to the network. Processing the files *should not wait* for the copy commands to finish. In theory, it's possible that a second copy command be sent before the first one has finished. Once all the files have been processed AND all the files have finished copying, I'd like a function called finalize() to be called.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Is `xcopy` an external program? You can use the `subprocess` module to start each copy job in the background, and wait on them once you have finished the processing before calling `finalize`.

Comment: @chepner that sounds like what I want to do. How do I call subprocess so that it doesn't interrupt the rest of the script, but finalize() DOES wait on all the xcopy commands to finish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll run `xcopy` in the background for each file, then wait on all the background jobs before calling `finalize`. Some assumptions:

1. `process` takes a file name as an argument, processes the given file, and returns the name of a result file that you'll copy
2. `bcopy` takes a source file name and a target as its two arguments
3. `destination` returns an appropriate target for a given source file

---

```
from subprocess import Popen

copy_jobs = []
for f in files_to_process:
    file_to_copy = process(f)
    where_to = destination(file_to_copy)
    # Popen forks and returns immediately, letting you move
    # on to the next file
    p = Popen(["xcopy", file_to_copy, where_to]
    copy_jobs.append(p)

# Block until all the job are done.
for job in copy_jobs:
    job.wait()
finalize()
```

Comment: ah, I was using call. Popen is exactly what I needed. thanks!

Comment: Ah, yes. `call` is just a [thin wrapper](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/subprocess.py#L315) around `Popen` that creates the instance and immediately calls `wait` on it.